# Faster "Resample with replacement by cluster"

Tags: r, performance, bootstrapping, resampling

I have the same question as [Resample with replacement by cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878667/resample-with-replacement-by-cluster), i.e. I want to do cluster bootstrapping. The best answer's approach to that question using `rbindlist(lapply(resampled_ids, function(resampled_id) df[df$id == resampled_id,]))` works, but because I have a big dataset, this resampling step is rather slow. My question is, is it possible to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sequence` to index. Demonstrated with a larger `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep.int(1:1e2, sample(100:200, 1e2, replace = TRUE))[1:1e4], X = rnorm(1e4))
resampled_ids <- sample(unique(df$id), replace = TRUE)

idx <- sequence(tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids], match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids])
s <- data.frame(id = df$id[idx], X = df$X[idx])
```

Benchmarking against the `rbindlist` solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(rbindlist = rbindlist(lapply(resampled_ids, function(x) df[df$id %in% x,])),
               sequence = {idx <- sequence(tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids], match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids])
                           data.frame(id = df$id[idx], X = df$X[idx])})
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  rbindlist 9480.4 9921.95 11470.567 10431.05 12555.35 31178.2   100
#>   sequence  406.7  444.55   564.873   498.10   545.70  2818.4   100
```

Note that creating a new `data.frame` from indexed vectors is much faster than row-indexing the original `data.frame`. The difference is much less pronounced if a `data.table` is used, but, surprisingly, the `rbindlist` solution becomes even slower:

```
microbenchmark(rbindlist = rbindlist(lapply(resampled_ids, function(x) df[df$id %in% x,])),
               sequence1 = df[sequence(tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids], match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids]),],
               sequence2 = {idx <- sequence(tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids], match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids])
                            data.frame(id = df$id[idx], X = df$X[idx])})
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr    min     lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  rbindlist 9431.9 9957.7 11101.545 10508.15 12395.25 15363.3   100
#>  sequence1 4284.5 4550.3  4866.891  4674.80  5009.90  8350.1   100
#>  sequence2  414.1  455.6   541.590   508.40   551.40  2881.1   100

    setDT(df)
    
microbenchmark(rbindlist = rbindlist(lapply(resampled_ids, function(x) df[df$id %in% x,])),
               sequence1 = df[sequence(tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids], match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids]),],
               sequence2 = {idx <- sequence(tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids], match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids])
                            data.table(id = df$id[idx], X = df$X[idx])})
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
#>  rbindlist 14877.4 15878.30 17181.572 16348.50 18527.6 22520.9   100
#>  sequence1   795.0  1016.80  1187.266  1101.95  1326.7  2566.5   100
#>  sequence2   386.4   441.75   556.226   473.70   500.9  3373.6   100
```

**Update**

To address the comment from jay.sf:

```
lens <- tabulate(df$id)[resampled_ids]
idx <- sequence(lens, match(unique(df$id), df$id)[resampled_ids])
s <- data.frame(cluster = rep.int(seq_along(resampled_ids), lens), id = df$id[idx], X = df$X[idx])
```

`cluster` corresponds to the index of `resampled_ids`.

Comment: Same problem as with _@f-privé_'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70889582/6574038), cluster with same ID can't be distinguished after bootstrap, this might be essential.

Comment: @jay.sf, It wasn't mentioned by the OP, but I can see how it could be important. Fortunately, including the `resampled_ids` in the `data.frame` is straightforward. See the update.

Comment: You nailed it, looks great now, upvoted!

Comment: Works much better! Just want to note that the ID must be numeric or factor for this, and if you have more than a single `X`, you might want to go the row index route using a `data.table` unless there's a faster way.

Comment: Good points. `tabulate` takes only numeric or factor, but easy to convert to numeric: `uid <- unique(df$id); df$id <- match(df$id, uid)` and then back to, e.g., character: `s <- data.frame(id = uid[df$id[idx]], X = df$X[idx])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = data.frame( id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3), X = rnorm(7) )
```

Try this:

```
ind_id <- split(seq_along(f$id), f$id)
samp_id <- sample(names(ind_id), replace = TRUE)
f[unlist(ind_id[samp_id]), ]
```

Comment: It's fast, but the problem is that in the result several draws of a cluster have the same ID and you can't distinguish them anymore. Try e.g. `set.seed(79) `.